# Using backgroundworker to handle data Streaming with Events in WinForms

Tags: c#, events, streaming, backgroundworker

I having some trouble in C#. I'm very new to C# events, so it's being difficult to me visualize the global solution to my problem. I'm supposed to do a WinForm to collect data from a LabJackDriver and graph it. I have a graph component ready, so my problem is how to do the basics.

I was searching were about some solutions here and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024472/how-to-graph-streaming-data-in-c). I'm trying some solution in this way.

Can you give some steps in how to start it? I must implement the fallowing interface:

```
public interface IStream {
    event StreamingDataArriveEventDelegate StreamingDataArrive;
    event StreamingStateChangeEventDelegate StreamingStateChange;

    void addAnalogPort(int portId);
    ISensorSource getSensorSource(int portId);

    void Start();
    void Stop();
    void Close();
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Pedro D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you start by creating a class that implements the interface, like this

```
public class MyClass : IStream
{
    public event StreamingDataArriveEventDelegate StreamingDataArrive;

    public event StreamingStateChangeEventDelegate StreamingStateChange;

    public void addAnalogPort(int portId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public ISensorSource getSensorSource(int portId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Replace all `throw new NotImplementedException();` with relevant code.

This has still not much to do with events. I suppose you also need to know how to fire an event.

Withing your `MyClass` when you need to notify the user that data has arrived you fire the `SteamingDataArrive` event like this:

```
if (StreamingDataArrive != null)
    StreamingDataArrive(this, new StreamingDataEventArgs("data"));
```

or whatever your delegate signature is.

To listen to the same event you subscribe the event to a handler

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.StreamingDataArrive += new StreamingDataArriveEventDelegate(myClass_StreamingDataArrive);
```

and create a handler

```
void myClass_StreamingDataArrive(object Sender, StreamingDataEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

you might need to change `StreamingDataEventArgs` to match your delegate signature.

Comment: Thank you Albin, your explanation made possible my solution.